# razor pages with firebase auth - where to put this token ? :)

Tags: firebase-authentication, razor-pages

i am working on web site with razor pages. part of the site should be accessed only by registred users. decided to go with firebase authentification (now with login and password ).

created everything necessary in firebase.
created backend code for user registration - works well.
created area which requires authorisation

```
            services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("User", "/");
            })
```

added jwt middleware

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
```

added code to login page to call firebase to get token

```
   function login()
        {
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    // Signed in
                    var user = userCredential.user;
                    // ...
                    alert("signed");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    alert(errorMessage);
                });
        }
```

got token from firebase.

if i'd call service next, i'd simply put token in "bearer" header.

tried to find how to add header to current browser for future requests and failed.

as i understand, i need this token to be added to auth header ? how ? :)

feeling dumb ;(  tried to google, but most samples are for using this token later with api calls.
or i am going in the wrong direction?

tia
ish

Answer (score 0):

well. it seems that it is not possible to add bearer from js, so i switched to cookies

in startup.cs use cookies

```
  options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = context =>
                        {
                            context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["bearer"];
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
```

code to login with firebase, put token into the cookie and redirect

```
        function login() {
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    // Signed in
                    var user = userCredential.user;
                    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function (idToken)
                    {
                        document.cookie = "bearer" + "=" + idToken;
                        window.location.href = "/user/index";
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        // Handle error
                    });
                    alert("signed");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    alert(errorMessage);
                });
        }
```

or the same with firebaseUI

```
        function login1()
        {
            ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
                signInSuccessUrl: '/User/index',
                signInOptions: [
                    {
                        provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                        requireDisplayName: false
                    }
                ],
                callbacks:
                {
                    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult, redirectUrl)
                    {
                        var user = authResult.user;
                        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function (idToken) {
                            document.cookie = "bearer" + "=" + idToken;
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            // Handle error
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```